# How to override jQueryValidation submit handler

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

How do you override the submit handler of a jQueryvalidation object with out overwriting all of the validation settings?

```
form1.validate({
      focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
      ignore: ".ignore", // validate all fields including form hidden input
      rules:{//rules excluded for brevity},
      submitHandler : function (form){ // I want to replace this function}
});
```

Then later, I want to override the submit handler.

```
form1.validate({

      submitHandler : function (form){ //some other logic}
});
```

This does not override the submit handler.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to override? Add an HTTP header, change the action URL, or ... ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/), you can define handler an following:

```
$("#myform").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    // do the things that you want to do
    form.submit();
  }
});
```